# How To refetch all the model inside a model in just one trigger without using loop

Tags: backbone.js

Hi I have question regarding refetching of the model on backbone

is there a way to fetch all model in a model

basically if i have my model and if that said model has an attribute of model as well i could trigger a re fetch and all the model inside that model will be re fetched

my current process is i would loop all through the attribute of a model and look for a model if i could find any i would fetch it. do you have a better way to do things? any suggestions?

This is my current code

```
_.each(self._getModels(entityRecordModel.attributes), function (model)
    {
       model.fetch();
    });
```

Comment: It depends on your API. If you have endpoints that can return several models (something like `GET /user?ids=1,2,3,4`), you could batch some of your requests. If not, you'll need to make several requests. This is the problem that [graphql](http://graphql.org/) aims to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The pub/sub pattern can help you here.

When you first initialised the attribute models, just subscribe to the main model's `sync` event and then fetch them as well.

If you want to to all this in one request, then use model's `parse` method to initialise/reset the attribute models.